# MySQL query to get only friends lists base on follow and followed back

Tags: mysql

How can I get the list of my friends when logged in. I have a follow table and user table as shown in the picture. I want to query only people who followed me and I follow back list excluding the current logged in username from the lists.

```
mysql> select * from follows;
| id | sender_username |receiver_username|
|:---|:------:|         -----:|
| 1  |  kate  |         james | me
| 2  |   john |         kate  |
| 3  |   james|         kate  |
| 4  |   niner|         manb  |
| 5  |   james|         manb  |
| 6  |   manb |         james |
| 7  |   bert |         oken  |
| 8  |   kate |         alex  |

mysql> select * from users;
| id | fullname   | user_Name   |
|:---|:------:    |         -----:|
|  1 | Phill Ja   | kate |
|  2 | Another H  | james| me
|  3 | Some Crazy | manb |
|  4 | Nameless   | nede |
```

my friend username list follow and follow back
exclude the current logged username james(me).

kate

manb

```
SELECT users.fullname, users.user_Name, 
follows.receiver_username,follows.sender_username 
from users 
inner join 
follows on users.user_Name=follows.sender_username 
where
users.user_Name ='name';
```

Comment: Change the database and instead of using the names in the `follows` table, use the `id` of the `user` Remember there are probably more than one Barry in the world

Comment: @RiggsFolly every user his unique username, no duplicate usernames

Comment: At a high level, with a bit more work, I think [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4cb4f1/5) is what you are looking for. As RiggsFolly noted, using IDs is generally better and recommended, however, since you’ve said the names are unique, we can then get rid of the IDs and use the names as keys. I removed extraneous columns, and instead of “follows” and “is following” I just said left and right, but you should get the gist.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether usernames are unique or not. you should be using ids. Besides, your question is neither related to PHP or mysqli

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thank you sir. I tried your code but doesn't give me what i want. I want a query friends where we both followed each other

Comment: @YourCommonSense I can change that later, I just need the right query to use

Comment: See if this is getting closer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e62e61/9 . Because you are storing data as keys, the user table doesn’t matter as much, although you can join that if needed, too. This just joins the follows table matching on both columns for bi-directional relationships. You’d want a WHERE in there, too, and you can arbitrarily pick one “table” as the truth to limit rows.

Comment: @ChrisHaas  this works but the issue here is how to exclude the current logged username from the friends results                                             
 select f1.sender_username as id1, f1.receiver_username as id2
from follows f1
inner join follows f2 
    on  f2.sender_username = f1.receiver_username
    and f2.receiver_username = f1.sender_username where f1.sender_username < f1.receiver_username 
and f1.sender_username='{$_SESSION['username']}' or f1.receiver_username='{$_SESSION['username']}'

Comment: If "Charlie" is logged in, you can just use a `NOT`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/355e7f/3

Comment: @ChrisHaas what if Bob or Alice is logged in NOT will show zero results. I guess you doesn't understand my question. I'm querying friends list where example Alice follow bob and Bob followed back

Comment: Okay, [last try](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/769c16/6), using your data except I've added your missing users. The first two queries are the same and they give you all users that have bidirectional relationships. The third uses a `VIEW` that I created which makes it simpler to re-use a sub-query. That query returns a list of all users in a bidirectional relationship, but in a single column with duplicates removed. It also optionally supports excluding a user, which might map to your logged in stuff. If this doesn't work, I don't think I can help any further, unfortunately.

Comment: @ChrisHaas almost sir.  manb shouldn't be showing on Kate friends list as both users are not following each other

Comment: Sorry about that, the condition should actually be inverted and in the interior query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/769c16/14

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thank you very much sir. Exactly what i want. Remain blessed forever